# Where should I change the value received from client? in nest.js

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

If the value { a: 1 } comes in from the client, I want to change it to { a : 1, b : 2 }

In this case, where does Nestjs recommend changing the data?

First. Method using transform decorator in dto
Second. service
Third, using typeorm with customRepository. (https://typeorm.io/#/custom-repository)

In the first case, I don't think I should use it if there is a value that needs to be processed before validation.

Of course I know that dto should have only getter and setter.

However, I am worried about whether I should use Transform decoder or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write like this
a = { a:1 }
b = { ...a, b:2 }

Comment: where ? dto ? or servcie or customRepository ?